# Python Beautifulsoup4 website parsing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some sports data from a website using Beautifulsoup4, but am having some trouble figuring out how to proceed.  I'm not that great with HTML, and can't seem to figure out the last bit of syntax necessary.  Once the data is parsed, I'm going to plug it into a Pandas dataframe.  I'm trying to extract the home team, away team, and score.  Here's my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv

url = 'http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/premier-league/results'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

def has_class_but_no_id(tag):
    return tag.has_attr('score')

writer = csv.writer(open("webScraper.csv", "w"))

for tag in soup.find_all('span', {'class':['team-away', 'team-home', 'score']}):
    print(tag)
```

here's a sample output:

```
<span class="team-home teams">
<a href="/sport/football/teams/newcastle-united">Newcastle</a> </span>
<span class="score"> <abbr title="Score"> 0-3 </abbr> </span>
<span class="team-away teams">
<a href="/sport/football/teams/sunderland">Sunderland</a> </span>
```

I need to store the home team (Newcastle), the score (0-3) and the away team (Sunderland) in three separate fields.  Essentially, I'm stuck trying to extract the "value" from each tag, and can't seem to figure out the syntax in `bs4`.  I need like a `tag.value` property, but all I have found in the documentation is a `tag.name` or `tag.attrs`.  Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each score unit is located inside a `<td class='match-details'>` element, loop over those to extract match details.

From there, you can extract the text from children elements using the [`.stripped_strings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) generator; just pass it to `''.join()` to get all strings contained in a tag. Pick `team-home`, `score` and `team-away` separately for ease of parsing:

```
for match in soup.find_all('td', class_='match-details'):
    home_tag = match.find('span', class_='team-home')
    home = home_tag and ''.join(home_tag.stripped_strings)
    score_tag = match.find('span', class_='score')
    score = score_tag and ''.join(score_tag.stripped_strings)
    away_tag = match.find('span', class_='team-away')
    away = away_tag and ''.join(away_tag.stripped_strings)
```

With an additional `print` this gives:

```
>>> for match in soup.find_all('td', class_='match-details'):
...     home_tag = match.find('span', class_='team-home')
...     home = home_tag and ''.join(home_tag.stripped_strings)
...     score_tag = match.find('span', class_='score')
...     score = score_tag and ''.join(score_tag.stripped_strings)
...     away_tag = match.find('span', class_='team-away')
...     away = away_tag and ''.join(away_tag.stripped_strings)
...     if home and score and away:
...         print home, score, away
... 
Newcastle 0-3 Sunderland
West Ham 2-0 Swansea
Cardiff 2-1 Norwich
Everton 2-1 Aston Villa
Fulham 0-3 Southampton
Hull 1-1 Tottenham
Stoke 2-1 Man Utd
Aston Villa 4-3 West Brom
Chelsea 0-0 West Ham
Sunderland 1-0 Stoke
Tottenham 1-5 Man City
Man Utd 2-0 Cardiff
# etc. etc. etc.
```

Comment: ahh I must have missed the match-details class, thanks! this is exactly what I needed.  I didn't know I could re-search within a tag using .find.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **tag.string** propery to get value of tag.

Refer to the documentation for more details.
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: I've been hunting through the documentation, but can't get the tag.string value to work.  It returns "none" every time.  If you look at the output, there's another "tag" within the tag I'm returning.  Is there a way set Beautifulsoup to return tags, only if it's within another tag?  For example above, I'd need to further search through the a tag, but only if the a tag is in a span tag.

Answer (score 0):

due to a redirect to here:
https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/premier-league/scores-fixtures

This is an update to the accepted answer, which is still correct. ping me if you edit your answer and i will delete this answer.

```
for match in soup.find_all('article', class_='sp-c-fixture'):
    home_tag = match.find('span', class_='sp-c-fixture__team sp-c-fixture__team--time sp-c-fixture__team--time-home').find('span').find('span')
    home = home_tag and ''.join(home_tag.stripped_strings)
    score_tag = match.find('span', class_='sp-c-fixture__number sp-c-fixture__number--time')
    score = score_tag and ''.join(score_tag.stripped_strings)
    away_tag = match.find('span', class_='sp-c-fixture__team sp-c-fixture__team--time sp-c-fixture__team--time-away').find('span').find('span')
    away = away_tag and ''.join(away_tag.stripped_strings)
    if home and score and away:
        print(home, score, away)
```