# python and beautifulsoup scraping football

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

was looking at a football scraping python program and found this on stackoverflow that suits my needs,
[Python Beautifulsoup4 website parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501949/python-beautifulsoup4-website-parsing/41664321#41664321)

what I am trying to do is modify it to only return scores for a particular date or set of dates, just cannot work out how to do this. But this just returns every result for every date .
Thx,
Mal

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv

url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/fa-cup/results'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

league =  'FA'

for games in soup.find_all('table', class_='table-stats'):
    played_tag = games.find('caption')
    played = played_tag and ''.join(played_tag.stripped_strings)
    print played

    for match in soup.find_all('td', class_='match-details'):
        home_tag = match.find('span', class_='team-home')
        home = home_tag and ''.join(home_tag.stripped_strings)
        score_tag = match.find('span', class_='score')
        score = score_tag and ''.join(score_tag.stripped_strings)
        away_tag = match.find('span', class_='team-away')
        away = away_tag and ''.join(away_tag.stripped_strings)

        if ( score.split('-')[0] > score.rsplit('-')[1] ):
            home_win = 1
        else:
            home_win = 0

        if (score.rsplit('-')[1] > score.split('-')[0] ):
            away_win = 1
        else:
            away_win = 0


        if home and score and away:
            print league,',',home,',',home_win,',',score
            print league,',',away,',',away_win,',',score
```

Comment: Show us how much you have done so far. We do not write code for you on this site.

Comment: Make the code a part of your question.

Comment: Please make your code a properly formatted part of your originally posted question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the date from the caption tag and add some logic to check against, for example, a list of desired dates.

Retrieve the date from caption tag string with regex and convert it into a datetime object:

```
date_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2})\w{2}\s([\w]+\s\d{4})') # pattern

played_date = re.findall(date_pattern, played_tag.get_text()) # find pattern in caption tag string played_tag
played_date = ' '.join(played_date[0])
played_date = datetime.strptime(played_date, '%d %B %Y') # convert it into datetime object
```

And define a list of dates you want to scrape:

```
list_of_dates = ['2017-01-07', '2017-01-06'] # put all dates to be print here

def dates_to_datetime(dates):
    """ Converts a list of date strings to a list of datetime objects """
    datetime_objs = []
    for d in dates:
        datetime_objs.append(datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    return datetime_objs

list_of_dates = dates_to_datetime(list_of_dates) # converts list_of_dates to list of datetime objects
```

Finally, you need to add a if statement to check if the date retrieved from the caption tag string is in your list of dates:

```
# check if retrieved date is in list_of_dates
if played_date in list_of_dates:
```

This is the complete example:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv


list_of_dates = ['2017-01-07', '2017-01-06'] # put all dates to be print here


def dates_to_datetime(dates):
    """ Converts a list of date strings to a list of datetime objects """
    datetime_objs = []
    for d in dates:
        datetime_objs.append(datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    return datetime_objs


list_of_dates = dates_to_datetime(list_of_dates) # converts list_of_dates to list of datetime objects

date_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2})\w{2}\s([\w]+\s\d{4})') # date pattern in <caption> tag i.e.: 9th January 2017

url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/fa-cup/results'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

league =  'FA'

for games in soup.find_all('table', class_='table-stats'):
    played_tag = games.find('caption')

    # retrieve date from caption tag
    played_date = re.findall(date_pattern, played_tag.get_text())
    played_date = ' '.join(played_date[0])
    played_date = datetime.strptime(played_date, '%d %B %Y')

    # check if retrieved date is in list_of_dates
    if played_date in list_of_dates:

        played = played_tag and ''.join(played_tag.stripped_strings)
        print played

        for match in soup.find_all('td', class_='match-details'):
            home_tag = match.find('span', class_='team-home')
            home = home_tag and ''.join(home_tag.stripped_strings)
            score_tag = match.find('span', class_='score')
            score = score_tag and ''.join(score_tag.stripped_strings)
            away_tag = match.find('span', class_='team-away')
            away = away_tag and ''.join(away_tag.stripped_strings)

            if ( score.split('-')[0] > score.rsplit('-')[1] ):
                home_win = 1
            else:
                home_win = 0

            if (score.rsplit('-')[1] > score.split('-')[0] ):
                away_win = 1
            else:
                away_win = 0


            if home and score and away:
                print league,',',home,',',home_win,',',score
                print league,',',away,',',away_win,',',score
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Thx for the input @Benjamin it has given me something to work on, unfortunately it does quite return the expected output, it lists all games played for example the last 3 lines of output , the game was actually played on Fri 4th Nov and not 6th Jan. I think for match in soup.find is returning all values.    2017-01-06 00:00:00 , FA , Southend United , 0 ,
2017-01-06 00:00:00 , FA , Eastleigh , 0 ,
2017-01-06 00:00:00 , FA , Swindon Town , 0 ,
>>>

Comment: I need to find a way to loop through all <td> tags for each instance of <table> tag and not all instances of <td> tag. Using the date comparison to select which instances of <table> tags to select.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Benjamin for putting me on the right track, a slight modification to his answer in order to check the date in the second loop , I know it is inefficient in that it will loop through all the data for each date selected but it does fulfil my end target.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv


list_of_dates = ['2016-11-06', '2016-11-05'] # put all dates to be print here


def dates_to_datetime(dates):
    """ Converts a list of date strings to a list of datetime objects """
    datetime_objs = []
    for d in dates:
        datetime_objs.append(datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    return datetime_objs


list_of_dates = dates_to_datetime(list_of_dates) # converts list_of_dates to list of datetime objects

date_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2})\w{2}\s([\w]+\s\d{4})') # date pattern in <caption> tag i.e.: 9th January 2017

url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/fa-cup/results'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

league =  'FA'

for games in soup.find_all('table', class_='table-stats'):
    played_tag = games.find('caption')

    # retrieve date from caption tag
    played_date = re.findall(date_pattern, played_tag.get_text())
    played_date = ' '.join(played_date[0])
    played_date = datetime.strptime(played_date, '%d %B %Y')

    # check if retrieved date is in list_of_dates
    if played_date in list_of_dates:

        for match in soup.find_all('td', class_='match-details'):

        # get parent match date            
            match_date = match.parent.parent.parent.caption
            if match_date == played_tag:
                home_tag = match.find('span', class_='team-home')
                home = home_tag and ''.join(home_tag.stripped_strings)
                score_tag = match.find('span', class_='score')
                score = score_tag and ''.join(score_tag.stripped_strings)
                away_tag = match.find('span', class_='team-away')
                away = away_tag and ''.join(away_tag.stripped_strings)

                if ( score.split('-')[0] > score.rsplit('-')[1] ):
                    home_win = 1
                else:
                    home_win = 0

                if (score.rsplit('-')[1] > score.split('-')[0] ):
                    away_win = 1
                else:
                    away_win = 0


                if home and score and away:
                    print played_date, ',', league,',',home,',',home_win
                    print played_date, ',', league,',',away,',',away_win
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better as it does not loop through all games only those needed.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv

f = open('/FACup.csv', 'wt')
writer = csv.writer(f)

list_of_dates = ['2017-01-09', '2017-01-08', '2017-01-07', '2017-01-06'] # put all dates to be print here


def dates_to_datetime(dates):
    """ Converts a list of date strings to a list of datetime objects """
    datetime_objs = []
    for d in dates:
        datetime_objs.append(datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    return datetime_objs


list_of_dates = dates_to_datetime(list_of_dates) # converts list_of_dates to list of datetime objects

date_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2})\w{2}\s([\w]+\s\d{4})') # date pattern in <caption> tag i.e.: 9th January 2017

url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/fa-cup/results'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

league =  'FA'

for games in soup.find_all('table', class_='table-stats'):
    played_tag = games.find('caption')

    # retrieve date from caption tag
    played_date = re.findall(date_pattern, played_tag.get_text())
    played_date = ' '.join(played_date[0])
    played_date = datetime.strptime(played_date, '%d %B %Y')

    # check if retrieved date is in list_of_dates
    if played_date in list_of_dates:

        for match in games.find_all('td', class_='match-details'):
            home_tag = match.find('span', class_='team-home')
            home = home_tag and ''.join(home_tag.stripped_strings)
            score_tag = match.find('span', class_='score')
            score = score_tag and ''.join(score_tag.stripped_strings)
            away_tag = match.find('span', class_='team-away')
            away = away_tag and ''.join(away_tag.stripped_strings)

            if ( score.split('-')[0] > score.rsplit('-')[1] ):
                home_win = 1
            else:
                home_win = 0

            if (score.rsplit('-')[1] > score.split('-')[0] ):
                away_win = 1
            else:
                away_win = 0


            if home and score and away:
                writer.writerow( (league, played_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), home, home_win, 'H') )
                writer.writerow( (league, played_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), away, away_win, 'A') )
    else:
        pass

f.close()
```